# Web Based Paint Editor for PSD based files

Tags: javascript, flash, html, photoshop

Here is the scenario.I am working on a project where i am given the task to design a Paint like interface on HTML and this paint interface will allow the users to paint the predefined "Hats" ..yes the hats that people wear.Now there is some twist to it.The requirement is :-

1) The Hat must be predefined image.i.e user can not draw the hat.He must select the hat from menu.

2) There must be predefined "Stripes"  which user selects from the menu.After selecting a stripe,that stripe will be applied to the existing Hat.Now these stripes are unique in style and will give the hat a unique look.

3)Allow the users to select a color from the menu and apply it either on the stripe or on the hat.See,the hat and stripe will be layered just like in Photoshop PSD file.So no layered image (stripe,hat) can superimpose on another.

4)Allow the users to remove the stripes or edit the color of stripes or edit the colour of hat.

That's it.These are the restrictions.Now,i know that the editor would be made on FLASH.but i am clueless on how to go about creating this thing. Is there an opensource web image editor available that will allow to play with PSD files ??? any ideas??

Comment: This question is overly broad, is not a coding question, and should be closed.

Comment: You can do this with the Canvas object in HTML/Javascript - probably your best bet if web is the delivery method.  I would suggest doing some web searches on the matter, as there are lots of tutorials for both HTML5/Flash alike on making these kinds of things

Comment: Don't get too hung up on using PSD files or you will hit a wall. Use the canvas element and just refresh it each time there is a change. Each 'layer' will be a variable referencing a canvas element whether it is the source image (hat), a stripe, or whatever. Every time you add or remove elements you can just redraw the canvas with or without those elements.

Comment: Still searching google for tutorials or anything which would give me a start on this web paint editing thing.Can anyone provide me links ?

Answer (score 0):

All of your PSD work has to be handled server-side.  If you are importing PSD files, you will very likely need to instantiate a copy of Photoshop (I believe you can access it with COM), or GIMP to export PNGs for each layer.

Client-side, I wouldn't bother with Flash.  You should be able to work with layers of images in the regular DOM, and manipulate with jQuery and what not.  If you need to do more advanced manipulation, dig into the canvas element.